# Required checkbox on checkout opencart

Tags: javascript, checkbox, opencart

I want to add a custom REQUIRED checkbox at the checkout page in my opencart 2.1.0.1 version (using journal theme).
I will create it easily with this `<input type="checkbox"` 
but how can i use javascript to make it required?

Answer (score 1):

Simply check for the `checked` attribute of your checkbox. According to that, submit your form or prevent it from submitting.

```js
function validate() {
  var checkbox = document.querySelector('#check');
  
  if (!checkbox.checked) {
    alert("Please check the checkbox!");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validate()" action="">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

**Edit:**

If you don't have a `form` in your HTML, you could disable the submit button until the checkbox is checked like this:

```js
function enableSubmit() {
  var button = document.querySelector('#btn');
  var checkbox = document.querySelector('#check');
  
  if (checkbox.checked == false) {
    button.setAttribute('disabled', '');
  } else if (checkbox.checked == true) {
    button.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="enableSubmit()"><button type="submit" id="btn" disabled>Submit</button>
```

**Edit 2**

If you want to display an error message only, toggling the visibility of a div would be an option:

```js
function validate() {
  var checkbox = document.querySelector('#check');
  var errorDiv = document.querySelector('#error');
  
  if (checkbox.checked == false) {
    errorDiv.style.display = "block";
  } else if (checkbox.checked == true) {
    errorDiv.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#error {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #f44b42;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" id="check"><button id="btn">Send</button>
<div id="error" style="display: block">Please check the checkbox.</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that i dont use `form`, this validation must work on the submit button on the checkout page

Comment: @ДобромирМилчев Please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: No, i want the button to be enabled all the time, just i want to display error message when the checkbox is not marked

Comment: @ДобромирМилчев I don't understand why you would do this because if it's required, the user shoudn't be able to submit without checking the checkbox, but anyway. I've updated my answer.